# Where clause affects Count() but not number of results returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have two tables:

Member

```
------------------------
| user_id | first_name |
------------------------
```

Messages

```
--------------------------------------------------
| sender_id | recipient_id | message_type | body |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to create a query that returns:

```
---------------------------------------------
| user_id | first_name | number_of_messages |
---------------------------------------------
```

The `number_of_messages` should only count the messages of a certain type, `message_type = 0`, however I still want to include the members in the result set that didn't send any messages of that type.

This is what I've got currently:

```
SELECT [user_id], [first_name], COUNT(sender_id) as number_of_messages
FROM [Member]
    FULL OUTER JOIN [Message] ON user_id = sender_id
where message_type = 0
GROUP BY [Member].[user_id], [first_name]
ORDER BY number_of_messages DESC
```

The problem with this query is any member who hasn't sent a message of type 0 will not be included in the result set. So I kind of want to use the `message_type = 0` clause to reduce the `number_of_messages`, however I don't want it to affect the number of results returned.

If there are any other optimizations I could make to my query that you see, please feel free to comment on them too.

Comment: You won't often need a FULL OUTER JOIN (though it is very convenient when you do need [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652009/i-cant-get-this-mysql-join-query-to-produce-the-desired-result/10658581#10658581)).  And, in this case specifically, you do not want a FULL OUTER JOIN; changing it to a LEFT OUTER JOIN would be sufficient.  `COUNT(sender_id)` will only count non-null rows, so the users who've sent no messages will show up with a count of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an OUTER JOIN:

```
   SELECT [user_id], [first_name], COUNT(m.sender_id) as number_of_messages
     FROM [Member]
LEFT JOIN [Message] m ON user_id = m.sender_id
                     AND m.message_type = 0
 GROUP BY [Member].[user_id], [first_name]
 ORDER BY number_of_messages DESC
```

Note that my query includes the `message_type` filter in the JOIN criteria -- NOT in the WHERE clause.  Placement is important with OUTER join syntax -- in the JOIN clause applies the criteria before the JOIN.  WHERE criteria is applied after the JOIN, and can give different results.

Comment: You could leave the message type filter in the main WHERE clause because `COUNT(expression)` (as distinct from `COUNT(*)`) only counts the number of non-null values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include members who do not have such message too, you simply have to remove m.message_type = 0, I don't see another way. Select everyone and filter the result to your needs later on with an IF clause.

Another solution might be that you create a dummy entry for each user with type 0 and filter those messages out when you use them.

Comment: It seems that you can do it by moving the WHERE clause to the JOIN clause :)