# MAX ACTIVITY DATE LOOKING FOR CODE OPTIMIZATION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the  query below  to find accounts which  need collection activity in sql server 2008 It works fine however I am doing a lot of work in power pivot once the data is inside it.  I am hoping to do this in the sql query to make it work more efficiently and limit the size of the output file.

The criteria is that an account has  a balance (xrxTrnLgr.Balance>0) and last activity happened more than 45 days ago.

The activity dates are represented by Max(xrxPatNotes.NoteDate) AS 'Max of NoteDate', Max(xrxTrnIcf.PostDate) AS 'Max of IcfPostDate', Max(xrxPat.EntryDate) AS 'Entry Date', Max(xrxPat.Coverage) AS 'Coverage', Max(xrxTrnPay.PostDate) AS 'Last Payment'

I am looking for a more efficient query that will return the last activity date as a column and only those accounts that are over 45 days with no activity. Please help.

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName, xrxTrnLgr.PatId
     , MAX(xrxTrnLgr.Balance) AS 'BALANCE'
     , Max(xrxPatNotes.NoteDate) AS 'Max of NoteDate'
     , Max(xrxTrnIcf.PostDate) AS 'Max of IcfPostDate'
     , Max(xrxPat.EntryDate) AS 'Entry Date'
     , Max(xrxPat.Coverage) AS 'Coverage'
     , Max(xrxPat.DctId) AS 'Doctor'
     , Max(xrxTrnPay.PostDate) AS 'Last Payment'
FROM xrxTrnLgr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxPatNotes ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxPatNotes.PatId
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxTrnIcf ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxTrnIcf.PatId
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxPat ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxPat.PatId
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxTrnPay ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxTrnPay.PatId
GROUP BY xrxTrnLgr.PatId, xrxTrnLgr.Balance
HAVING (xrxTrnLgr.Balance>0)
```

Comment: does your query give you the output you want or does it give an error? the query seems be incomplete with no clause for `HAVING`

Comment: It does work however I am bringing this into power pivot and I am looking for a more efficient way to  bring in just the accounts that are over 45 days inactive.

Comment: Please update the question to add the having clause and stress that it works fine and change the title to mention you are looking for code optimization

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have done this.  Any other suggestions.  I am currently able to get all dates into an output however I then need to figure out the max date of the four dates and then see if it is greater than 45 days from today and it is inneficient.

Comment: So you are not getting what you want right? then clearly mention the table structures, current output and desired output like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652009/i-cant-get-this-mysql-join-query-to-produce-the-desired-result)

Comment: Does table `xrxTrnLgr` has column `PatId` as primary key?  By the way using `HAVING (max(xrxTrnLgr.Balance)>0)` instead of `HAVING (xrxTrnLgr.Balance>0)` would be more reasonable.

Comment: Yes, PatId is the primary key.

Comment: Any particular reason to shout in title?

Comment: Take the effort to format.  And not the posted query does not run.  You cannot have a group by in an aggregate - xrxTrnLgr.Balance.

Comment: Sorry for those who are trying to help.  I am obviously not a programmer and just trying to solve a business problem.  I am new to posting on this site and the structure of my question as well as my SQL knowledge is very limited and I apologize for this.  Any help is greatly appreciated and I will try to be more concise with my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
with Acts (PatId, ActiveDate) as
(
SELECT PatId, max(NoteDate )
  FROM xrxPatNotes 
 GROUP BY PatId
UNION 
SELECT PatId, max(PostDate)
  FROM xrxTrnIcf 
  GROUP BY PatId
-- continue to UNION other activity tables
),
     ActsMoreThan45Days as
(
SELECT PatId,max(ActiveDate) as ActiveDate
  FROM Acts
 GROUP BY PatId
HAVING DATEDIFF(d, max(ActiveDate), GETDATE()) >= 45
)
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName, 
       xrxTrnLgr.PatId, 
       xrxTrnLgr.Balance, 
       A45.ActiveDate, 
       xrxPat.Coverage,
       xrxPat.DctId AS Doctor
  FROM xrxTrnLgr 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ActsMoreThan45Days A45
    ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = A45.PatId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxPat 
    ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxPat.PatId
 WHERE xrxTrnLgr.Balance>0
```

1. Instead of grouping by balance column on xrxTrnLgr, join max active date to table xrxTrnLgr, that would be much faster.
2. To aggregate all activity tables and get max active date separately, then compare all these max active dates, would be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQL Server has not GREATEST function, so you can do it as a UDF like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Greatest(@date1 datetime, @date2 datetime) RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    IF @date1 > @date2
        RETURN @date1
    RETURN @date2
END
```

And then do your query like this:

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName,
    xrxTrnLgr.PatId,
    MAX(xrxTrnLgr.Balance) AS 'BALANCE',
    dbo.Greatest(MAX(xrxPatNotes.NoteDate), dbo.Greatest(Max(xrxTrnIcf.PostDate), dbo.Greatest(Max(xrxPat.EntryDate), Max(xrxTrnPay.PostDate)) as 'Last Activity',
    Max(xrxPat.Coverage) AS 'Coverage',
    Max(xrxPat.DctId) AS 'Doctor'
FROM  xrxTrnLgr LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxPatNotes ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxPatNotes.PatId
LEFT OUTER JOIN  xrxTrnIcf ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxTrnIcf.PatId
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxPat ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxPat.PatId
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxTrnPay ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxTrnPay.PatId
GROUP BY xrxTrnLgr.PatId, xrxTrnLgr.Balance
HAVING (xrxTrnLgr.Balance>0) AND 
    DATEDIFF(d, dbo.Greatest(MAX(xrxPatNotes.NoteDate), dbo.Greatest(Max(xrxTrnIcf.PostDate), dbo.Greatest(Max(xrxPat.EntryDate), Max(xrxTrnPay.PostDate)), GETDATE()) > 45
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName, xrxTrnLgr.PatId
     , MAX(xrxTrnLgr.Balance) AS 'BALANCE'
     , Max(xrxPatNotes.NoteDate) AS 'Max of NoteDate'
     , Max(xrxTrnIcf.PostDate) AS 'Max of IcfPostDate'
     , Max(xrxPat.EntryDate) AS 'Entry Date'
     , Max(xrxPat.Coverage) AS 'Coverage'
     , Max(xrxPat.DctId) AS 'Doctor'
     , Max(xrxTrnPay.PostDate) AS 'Last Payment'
FROM xrxTrnLgr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxPatNotes ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxPatNotes.PatId
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxTrnIcf   ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxTrnIcf.PatId
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxPat      ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxPat.PatId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxTrnPay   ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxTrnPay.PatId
where xrxTrnLgr.Balance > 0
GROUP BY xrxTrnLgr.PatId 
HAVING datediff(dd, MAX(xrxTrnLgr.Balance)   , getdate()) > 45
   and datediff(dd, Max(xrxPatNotes.NoteDate), getdate()) > 45
   ...
```

you may be looking for or